# ASP.net How to loop through the sql server and update table button image?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datatable

I have create a table which each cell contain button with image:

**car.aspx**

```
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" class="seatCell" valign="middle" runat="server">
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ToolTip="Window Side" ImageUrl="~/Images/available_seat_img.gif" runat="server" />1</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" class="seatCell" valign="middle" runat="server">
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" ImageUrl="~/Images/available_seat_img.gif" runat="server" />2</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell ID="TableCell3" class="seatCell" valign="middle" runat="server">
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" ImageUrl="~/Images/available_seat_img.gif" runat="server" />3</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell ID="TableCell4" class="seatCell" valign="middle" runat="server">&nbsp;xxx</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

I create a table in SQL server:

```
Car         Date          Seat1     Seat2      Seat3
Honda       August        NULL      Book       Book
Proton      August        Book      NULL       NULL
```

So by default the seat map is set as NULL which mean will display the image:~/Images/available_seat_img.gif.
Anyone have idea how to loop throught this sql server if the user select car modal is Honda then the Table image will be change to book.gif if the table cell in sql server for Seat column is Book?

Please help, thanks.

Comment: You just want to update the data in your sql server? It isn't very clear what you are trying to do here at all. I would suggest that some normalization of your table would help you. You appear to have what is known as "repeating groups" which violates 1NF.

Comment: the image for the button is display based on the data in sql server, for example the sql data is Book mean not NULL, the image display will be book.gif

Comment: I can't see your screen and have no knowledge of your project. Are you trying to update the database or something else?